# If statement not executing inside module in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, module

I'm confused, the if statement should by all means run imo, but of course this is programming so its not going to work.

```
def create_player():
    name = str()
    names = []
    print("hey there")
    if numberofplayers == 2:
        name = input("Please enter Player 1's name: ")       
        names.append(name)
        name = input("Please enter Player 2's name: ")
        names.append(name)
    elif numberofplayers == 3:
        name = input("Please enter Player 1's name: ")       
        names.append(name)
        name = input("Please enter Player 2's name: ")
        names.append(name)
        name = input("Please enter Player 3's name: ")
        names.append(name)
    elif numberofplayers == 4:
        name = input("Please enter Player 1's name: ")       
        names.append(name)
        name = input("Please enter Player 2's name: ")
        names.append(name)
        name = input("Please enter Player 3's name: ")
        names.append(name)
        name = input("Please enter Player 4's name: ")
        names.append(name)
        print("Welcome to the game " + names[0] + ", " +names[1]+ ", "+names[2]+ " and "+names[3]+"!")

print("test")
numberofplayers = int(0)
numberofplayers = input("# of players")
create_player()
print ("aha")
```

(By the way this code is not be any means anywhere near finished) The random print operations were there for testing, the program seems to ignore the whole if statement, as it prints all of the print operations outside of the if statement, but none that are inside the statement. Any help would be very much appreciatted, thank you in advance.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: You need to add `global numberofplayers` inside `create_player()`

Comment: Please fix your indents in the sample code you provided.

Comment: Thank you :) and I think its 3.3, not sure, on a school computer.

Comment: You can simplify this: `for n in range(numberofplayers): names.append(input("Enter player {0}'s name".format(n+1)))`. This removes much of the duplication and works for any number of players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `numberofplayers` to `int`, otherwise you are comparing and `int` and a `string`:

```
numberofplayers = int(input("# of players"))
```

[`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?#input) in Python 3 returns a string object, in difference with former Python2's `input()`.

This is what is going on:

```
>>> a = input()
2
>>> a == 2
False
>>> a == '2'
True
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see now what is happening, the if statement wasnt finding the items stated in the argument.

Comment: Actually, the if statement wasn't succeeding because the comparisons yielded False

Answer (score 1):

While Paulo's answer fixes your immediate problem, there's a few other things to point out.

- Since your function creates at least two players, name if correctly: `create_players`. It avoids confusion later.
- Don't rely on globals or values outside of your function scope. You should pass them explicitly into your functions.

  ```
  def create_players(numberofplayers):
      ...

  numberofplayers = int(input('# of players'))
  create_players(numberofplayers)
  ```
- These lines don't do anything useful:

  ```
  name = str()

  numberofplayers = int(0)
  ```

  You don't need to define variables as types in order to use them, and you're immediately replacing these with real values.
- Your branching `if-elif` would be better as a single `for` loop:

  ```
  names = []
  for player in range(1, numberofplayers+1):
      names.append( input("Please enter Player %d's name: " % player) )
  print('Welcome to the game ' + ' and '.join([', '.join(names[:-1]), names[-1]]) + '!')
  ```

Comment: What do you mean by pass explicitly? Sorry I'm relatively new to programming, studying it at high school.

Comment: When you have `x = 1; do_something_with_x()` you're relying on `x` being defined outside of the function. It's generally a lot more flexible to do `x = 1; do_something(x)`; here it's passing the value into the function rather than finding it outside of it.